# upload avatar with some key value data in Postman for laravel web application

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-api

any body can help me
i wanna make a register which is have these parameter

this is my RegisterRequest for validation

```php
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'     => 'required',
            'email'    => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'username' => 'nullable|string|min:5|unique:users,username',
            'avatar'   => 'nullable|mimes:jpge,jpg,png',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:5',
            
        ];
    }
```

and this is my Postman Setup
**Headers** setup
[image]

**Body / form-data** setup
[image]

**Body /raw**
[image]

---

and this is my **register** method `dd()` code

```php
 public function register(RegisterRequest $request)
    {

        dd(
            $request->all(),
            $request->avatar,
            $request->hasFile('avatar'),
            $request->file('avatar')
        );


    }
```

and this is the result in the Postman

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its solved By `removing` this from **Headers**

**Content-Type : application/json**

Answer (score 0):

If you post JSON you need to encode your image to base64 or link (url) to image and post it in the body parameter, Also change your validation to base64 or url. try this:

```
{
  "name" : "ali",
  "email" : "tes@tes.tes",
  "username" : "ali",
  "avatar" : "data:image/png;base64,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",
  "password" : "123456",
  "password_confirmation" : "123456",
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use form-data instead of raw in postman please check screenshot https://prnt.sc/XP4UA0rHKoOS